# Are there rules for tying up an awake enemy in combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

I am looking for rules in D&D 5e that can clarify the process of tying up an enemy (someone that does not want to be tied up) fully capable of defending themself.

Comment: Looks like someone found a close match to your question. If that doesn't match what you're after you can [edit] your question. Please take the time to visit our [tour] for more details on the site and how we run.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage If this is a possible, dupe, can we get a link to the other question for easier comparison?

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [How do I adjudicate attempting to put manacles on an unwilling creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123869/52137), [Are there rules for using manacles in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/101346/52137), [Chaining up a creature in combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128566/52137)

Comment: Nice! This answer my question, but I think not deleting it can make it easier for someone, like me, to find the answer even searching for "tying" related questions.

Comment: @HeitorP.C. As a matter of fact, we prefer to keep duplicate questions around rather than delete them for that exact reasoon

Comment: Thanks very much to everyone!